# Progressbar + button in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is it possible to combine behaviour of TextButton and Progressbar in libgdx. So that button will be disabled initially, but a progress will be shown in the background. Is there any easy way to implement it?

Comment: You can use the disabled state for the button initially. Whenever you decide it's ready enable the button. Set a disable image for the button in the corresponding "slot".